# How to set color of microphone at "x-webkit-speech" text input?

Tags: html

The text input has black background and white ink color. (And I plan to keep it.)
How can I set the color of the webkit's microphone image other than black?
'-webkit-text-fill-color' will active only after I click on the microphone image, which I cannot see until click, because it has black color on black background.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="sid" x-webkit-speech />
```

CSS:

```
#sid {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:#ffffff;
}
```

You can test here (with gray background): [jsfiddle.net/W65Be/](http://jsfiddle.net/W65Be/)

Answer (score 4):

You can add some style to `input::-webkit-input-speech-button`, that's all you need.

example :

```
input::-webkit-input-speech-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;width: 50px;height: 30px;background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

*always add `-webkit-appearance: none;`